# Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.captureVisibleTab: Failed to capture tab: unknown error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to take screenshots of all tabs and compress them in my chrome extensions. My problem is in this error: `Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.captureVisibleTab: Failed to capture tab: unknown error at Object.callback` in line of code `chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(function(screenshotUrl)`. This error appears arbitrarily.
Here is the program code:

```
var arr = [];
var i;
var n;
var TAB;

function allScreen(){
    var currentTab = TAB[i];
    chrome.tabs.update(currentTab.id, {selected: true}, function (){
        chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(function(screenshotUrl) {
            var newImage  = new Image();
            newImage.src = screenshotUrl;

            newImage.onload = function(){
                    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                    canvas.width = 400;
                    canvas.height = 300;
                    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(newImage, 0, 0, newImage.width, newImage.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1)
                    arr.push(data);
                    i++;
                    if (i < n){allScreen(TAB);}
            }
        });
    });
}

function screenShot(){
    arr = [];
    chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(null, function(tabs){
        i = 0;
        n = tabs.length;
        TAB= tabs;
        allScreen(tabs, function(){
            console.log("finish");
        });
    });
}
```

Can anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I've had security issues trying to convert `<img src>` to data URI using a `<canvas>` like this in injected scripts - I'm not sure why you need to as the output of `chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab` is [already a data URI](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-captureVisibleTab).

I'm a little confused by the parameters passed to `allScreen` as they're never referenced from inside it - instead you're switching to global variables.

You can make this a lot easier with promises. First refactor `allScreen` to become a promise that resolves when the screenshot has been taken:

```
function screenshotTab(currentTab){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        chrome.tabs.update(currentTab.id, {selected: true}, () => {
            if (chrome.runtime.lastError)
                // Return as an error for the awaited catch block
                reject(`Error selecting tab ${chrome.runtime.lastError}`));
            else
                chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(uri => {
                    if (chrome.runtime.lastError)
                        reject(`Error getting screenshot ${chrome.runtime.lastError}`));
                    else
                        resolve(uri);
                });
        });
    });
}
```

Another promise can give us the tabs:

```
function getTabsInWindow() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(null, tabs => {
            if (chrome.runtime.lastError)
                reject(`Error getting tabs in window ${chrome.runtime.lastError}`));
            else
                resolve(tabs);
        });
    });
}
```

Then we can use `map` to apply it to all the tabs:

```
async function screenShotAll() {
    // We can use await to get the result of the promise
    const tabs = await getTabsInWindow();

    // map the collection of tabs into promises waiting for screenshots
    const runningScreenshots = tabs.map(screenshotTab);

    // Use await with Promise.all to wait for them all to call back
    const result = await Promise.all(runningScreenshots);

    console.log('done', result);
    return result;
}
```

This function now returns a promise, so you can do:

```
// async-await syntax
const finalResult = await screenShotAll();

// Or promise syntax works too
screenShotAll().then(finalResult => { /* deal with result */ });
```

Finally you can use a library (such as [`chrome-extension-async`](https://github.com/KeithHenry/chromeExtensionAsync)) to create all the promise wrappers and `chrome.runtime.lastError` checking for you.